# How can I calculate the number of moves made between the stacks?

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

In my current assignment I'm supposed to move elements between three stacks. I have one more method to write: getNumberOfMoves() and it should calculate the number of moves made between the stacks.

I want to add a calculator of some sort but the assignment says that I should write a more specific method for this. Any suggestions for how one can calculate the number of moves using a method?

Also, I'm having trouble with the method move(). I'm supposed to use push() and pop() from the other class. I did some just too see what happens, see code below, but I think I'm supposed to do it with recursion. So the base cases then should be that if the first stack 'from' only contains one element, then this should be moved directly to 'to', otherwise the last element should be moved to the 'help' stack and then to 'to'.
But, the question is, if I'm doing it recursively, shouldn't I be calling the method within the method? Then how am I supposed to use pop() and push()?

Thanks in advice!

```
public class StackPlay {

   /**
    * Returns the current number of times an element has been moved
    * @return the number of moves
    */   
   public static long getNumberOfMoves() {


   }

   public static void move(myStack from, 
                           myStack to, 
                           myStack help, 
                           int n) {
help.push(from.pop());
to.push(help.pop());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int size = 3;
      myStack from = new myStack(size);
      myStack to = new myStack();
      myStack help = new myStack();
      System.out.println("Start state");
      System.out.println("   From: " + from);
      System.out.println("   To:   " + to);
      System.out.println("   Help: " + help);
      System.out.println("   Number of moves: " + getNumberOfMoves());
      move(from, to, help, size);
      System.out.println("End state");
      System.out.println("   From: " + from);
      System.out.println("   To:   " + to);
      System.out.println("   Help: " + help);
      System.out.println("   Number of moves: " + getNumberOfMoves());
   }
}
```

and separate class:

```
public class myStack {

  private ArrayList<Integer> specStack;

  public myStack() {
    specStack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  public myStack(int n) {
    this.specStack = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        specStack.add(i, n-i);
      }
    }


  public void push(int x) { 
    if (specStack.size() == 0) {
      specStack.add(x);
    }
    else if (x > specStack.get(specStack.size() -1)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Number too high");
    }
    else {
      specStack.add(x);
    }
  }


  public int pop() {
    if (specStack.size() == 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Empty stack");
    }
    else {
      int length = specStack.size() -1;
      int topEl = specStack.get(length);
      specStack.remove(length);
      return topEl;

    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    String arrList = "[";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < specStack.size(); i++) { 
      if (i == specStack.size() -1) {
        arrList = arrList + specStack.get(i);
      } 
      else {
        arrList = arrList + specStack.get(i) + ",";}
    }
  arrList = arrList + "]";
  return arrList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Michelangleo. Welcome to SO. Is this Tower of Hanoi problem. It seems like it is. Search for that if you are stuck. Do give it a proper try. **Hint:** Think of in terms of how many moves will it take for 2, 3, 4.... disks. You will find the pattern for yourself.

Comment: OK I see, mathematically this would mean that the number of moves are 2^n -1. So if I was to implement this recursively.. then the base case is that if the 'to' and 'help' stacks are empty then 0 moves occurred, since all numbers are stuck in the 'from' stack. If the 'to' stack is full then the number of moves equals 2^n -1. Is that a good solution?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Trying to implement this, I'm not succeeding at trying to use any variables associated with the stacks. I can't use to or size or n or any variable. How can I solve this? What am I supposed to call here?